# Execute code if not a touch screen and also width is 960px or over

Tags: jquery

These two conditionals work fine:

```
if ( jQuery(window).width() > 959 ) {
    // do something if the browser window is 960px or more
}
if (!Modernizr.touch) {
    // do something if not a touch screen
}
```

I need to only execute some code if the device is not a touch screen, and its also over 960px wide. For some reason this isnt working:

```
if    (    (!Modernizr.touch) && (jQuery(window).width() > 959) {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing parenthesis here:

```
                                       //      here------↓
if( (!Modernizr.touch) && (jQuery(window).width() > 959) ) {

}
```

Comment: Actually, it's a closing parenthesis, bracket is `]`, brace is '}'. Pedant mode off.

Comment: oh come on, bracket is shorter. Edited anyway